# 301 Redirect to Nginx & keep the URL

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have a domain hosted at an ISP. Let's say - hello.mysite.com.
I have set up an nginx http server to serve static html at home. Let's say public ip address of nginx http server is 37.252.120.91. I have configured a 301 forward from hello.mysite.com to http->>//37.252.120.91. This forwards works well but I lose the original url in my browser. I would like to see the contents from http://37.252.120.91 but I still want to see http://hello.mysite.com on my browser address bar. I have tried the following setting in my nginx.conf file but it has no effect.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name  hello.mysite.com;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://37.252.120.91/;
    }
}
```

Can you help fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A redirect is just that, a redirect. You are directed elsewhere, away from the original site. You can't do what you're asking at a web server level alone.

You'll need to use something like an iframe: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe

That way, you can set up hosting on hello.mysite.com which iframes http://37.252.120.91 and appears to be the same content.